# Transmitting raw packet in when 802.11 miniport driver in NetMon mode

Tags: sockets, wifi-direct, wifi, ndis

As per msdn documentation, while in NetMon mode, the miniport driver can only receive the packet based on the filter settings. The miniport driver can not send the packet.

But I need to transmit the raw packet while the miniport driver in NetMon mode. Can any body suggest, how can I send raw packets from the miniport driver ?

Answer (score 0):

`NetMon` mode instructs the miniport driver to receive packets according to the filter specified by the `OS`. However, from your proprietary miniport driver you can send anything if layers that reside below miniport (`FW`, `HW`) allow it (`OS` is not and can not be involved in this). Of course, that would be a violation of the `OS` specification for `NetMon` mode, but that's entirely different issue.